# jQuery Datatables selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I was trying to create a jQuery datatable using a data object. The table gives fine output but the thing is that the selection in the datatable is not working. It's supposed to put a class `selected` on the row when I select. Also I have set the select option to `true`.

```html
dTable = $(tContainer).DataTable({
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    processing:true,
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');
                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
    data: dataArr,
    destroy: true,
    select:true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select:true
>
> From [doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select): This option can be used to configure the Select extension for DataTables during the initialisation of a DataTable.

The snippet with the added required libraries:

```js
var dataArr = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
[ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
[ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
[ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
[ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
[ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
[ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
[ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
[ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
[ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
[ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
[ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
[ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
[ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
[ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
[ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
[ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
[ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
[ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
[ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
[ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
[ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
[ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
[ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
[ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
[ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
[ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
[ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
[ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
[ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
[ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];


dTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    processing:true,
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },

        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
    ],
    data: dataArr,
    destroy: true,
    select:true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.js">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

In any case you can achieve the same result adding the following event handler:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        dTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );
```

The snippet:

```js
var dataArr = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
[ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
[ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
[ "Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000" ],
[ "Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500" ],
[ "Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900" ],
[ "Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500" ],
[ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600" ],
[ "Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560" ],
[ "Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000" ],
[ "Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600" ],
[ "Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500" ],
[ "Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750" ],
[ "Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500" ],
[ "Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000" ],
[ "Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500" ],
[ "Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000" ],
[ "Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500" ],
[ "Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000" ],
[ "Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000" ],
[ "Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450" ],
[ "Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600" ],
[ "Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000" ],
[ "Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575" ],
[ "Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650" ],
[ "Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850" ],
[ "Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000" ],
[ "Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000" ],
[ "Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400" ],
[ "Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500" ],
[ "Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000" ],
[ "Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500" ],
[ "Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050" ],
[ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];

dTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
    processing:true,
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy' },
        { extend: 'csv' },
        { extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile' },
        { extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile' },

        {
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function (win) {
                $(win.document.body).addClass('white-bg');
                $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                $(win.document.body).find('table')
                        .addClass('compact')
                        .css('font-size', 'inherit');
            }
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
    ],
    data: dataArr,
    destroy: true,
    select:true
});

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        dTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the file `dataTables.select.js` or `dataTables.select.min.js`. They can be found [here](https://cdn.datatables.net/select/).